# For $f(x) = 2x^3$ Find the maximum and minimum values, given the closed interval $-3 \le x \le 3$

Tags: derivatives

> For $f(x) = 2x^3$ Find the maximum and minimum values, given the
>   closed interval $-3 \le x \le 3$.

Turning points occur when $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=6x^2$

I can use the second derivative to find out whether a value is a maximum or minimum.  $f''(x)>0$ is a minimum and $f''(x)<0$ is a maximum.

$f''(x) = 12 x$

$f''(-3) = 12(-3) = -36$ so I would say this a maximum but if I plug this into the underived function I get -54 for -3 and 54 for 3.

3 is the maximum and -3 is the minimum unless I am missing something.

Comment: The function $x^3$ is increasing in our interval, so the differentiation stuff is unnecessary. Min value is $-54$, max value is $54$.

Comment: Differentiation is not only unnecessary but useless for this function since it has no local maximum or minimum points!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a closed interval, the min/max occurs either where $f'(x)=0$ or at the endpoints. You don't need to check for the second derivative.

$f'(x)=6x^2=0$ at $x=0$, but it doesn't change sign there, so there is no extreme value.

The endpoints are $f(-3)=54$ and $f(3)=-54$, so the maximum and minimum must occur there.

Therefore $\min f=-54$ and $\max f=54$.

Answer (score 1):

-3 and 3 are'nt min or max (local) , they are just the end/start of the domain. 
you find the "suspected" min/max by comparing f'(x) to zero. And than check f'' which in this case wont do you any good, because in this case 0 is an inflection point.
Because of that , your only two places to check are -3,3 and they are your
max/ min (global)